# How to Go Back on Cancel in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Sorry if it is a very basic question. But I would like to know how can I go back to the previous page if  I click on the `Cancel` button in a form page.

The form page has a `Submit` and `Cancel`

On Submit, it goes to the `route.php` and gets the `Route::post('', '');` section. What about the Cancel button with a `name=cancel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go back on a button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ URL::previous() }}'">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4

```
<a href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: I am talking about a button. Not a link

Comment: Ahh ok. I quote a link because some people use css frameworks like Bootstrap to make a link looks like a button :) <a class="btn btn-default"></a>